# Suggested way to setup drupal to handle multiple subsites / subdomains?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

Looking for some examples of folks successfully using Drupal on multiple subdomains. Is there a good way to go about using a single drupal install to manage multiple subsites like so:

- Siteone.domain.com
- Sitetwo.domain.com
- Sitethree.domain.com

Etc….

All of these subsites have separate information, but some of it could be related here and there, so having it available to each subsite would be a benefit... thinking Entities here I suppose. One database and one core to update would be ideal. Any issues with setting it up? Problems with content types or entities?

I've seen:

- http://www.aegirproject.org/ However, this is multiple drupal sites as far as I can see...
- https://www.drupal.org/project/domain This seems like a near perfect fit. Anyone successfully utilizing this?

Comment: The domain module reports almost 15000 installs so I think it's pretty safe to say people are successfully utilizing that. It is also a very well supported module. As you say, the two options (there are potentially others) are also very different. It really depends on your specific requirements as to what the best multi-site solution is so no one here is going to be able to give you a "correct" answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @rooby. I updated my title to "suggested" :). You are right, there are going to be different ideas for each. I'm looking for some real world input from folks if that can be given.

Comment: What kind of real world input do you want? It's a pretty broad topic. It seems like more of a discussion/blog post type thing than a question/answer type thing. If you wanted to choose an option then based on your very brief requirements I would say use the domain module but I would want more detailed and complete requirements if it were me making the decision for a site I was building.

Comment: One of the architects of Drupal wrote a post about this: http://www.palantir.net/blog/multi-headed-drupal

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [multisite](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) setup?

> This is particularly useful for managing the code since each upgrade
>   only needs to be done once. Each site will have its own database and
>   its own configuration settings, so each site will have its own
>   content, settings, enabled modules, and enabled theme. However, the
>   sites are sharing a code base and web document root, so there may be
>   security concerns with multiple administrators

I've used this for setting up one codebase and then creating multisite installs of the codebase for clients who want similar websites. Multisites can be done as either subdomains (ie subdomain.domain.com) or subsites (ie domain.com/subsite). Each multisite install has its own database, and can have its own modules or theme even, but if there is core functionality you can put it in the root codebase and it will be shared across all multisites.

Comment: I have considered using this. The setup doesn't seem as straight fwd as the domain module for example. Has maintenance been easy for these setups for you?

Comment: Yes, I've had very good luck with this setup. Just have to update one set of code and it works across all subsites. I do have to go through with Drush to run updb on the subsites (when needed), but other than that it works great.